# Why Integer and Double operations acting differently?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE*2 == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE-1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE+1 == Double.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

For the above we are getting below response

```
true
false
true
true
```

For Double.MAX_VALUE+1 == Double.MAX_VALUE this is true, but why Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE is false?

And why does Double.MAX_VALUE*2 == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY return true?

Can anyone provide valid reasons and explanations?

I went through the JavaDoc, but I'm not getting much useful info.

Answer (score 6):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE` returns **false** because of **integer overflow**. The maximum value of an int is 2147483647, so when you add 1 to it, the result exceeds the maximum value and overflows to -2147483648. Therefore, **Integer.MAX_VALUE+1** evaluates to **Integer.MIN_VALUE**, which is not equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

`Double.MAX_VALUE+1 == Double.MAX_VALUE` returns **true** due to **floating-point precision**. The maximum value of a double is 1.7976931348623157E308, and when you add 1 to it, the result remains the same ***due to the limited precision of floating-point arithmetic***. Therefore, Double.MAX_VALUE+1 evaluates to Double.MAX_VALUE, **which is equal** to Double.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE+1` rolls around to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  And likewise `Integer.MIN_VALUE-1` results in `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  So your second comparison will return `false`.

```
int start1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE-5;
int start2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE+5;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(++start1 + "   " + --start2);
}
```

```
2147483643   -2147483644
2147483644   -2147483645
2147483645   -2147483646
2147483646   -2147483647
2147483647   -2147483648
-2147483648   2147483647
-2147483647   2147483646
-2147483646   2147483645
-2147483645   2147483644
-2147483644   2147483643
```

Floating point values have finite precision so the addition of  values near the limits of that precision don't affect the comparisons.

For more on floating point values and how they are represented in floats and doubles check out [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).